# Corruption of value on the stack

Tags: c++, garbage-collection

In the code below I find that the value of N is being replaced (to 0) after reading a certain number of inputs. I believe this is happening because I have allocated the K and S arrays on the stack. I was wondering if my conclusion is right ? I used to code in C a long time back and switch to python and other scripting languages. So, somewhere my memory management seems to have gone for a toss.

```
ofstream cop("op1.txt");
ifstream cinp("in1.txt", ios::binary);
int T, t=1;
cinp >> T;
for(;t <= T;t++){
    fflush(stdin);
    long D;
    int N;
    long K[N], S[N];
    cinp >> D >> N;
    double times[N], max = 0;
    cout << D << " " << N << endl;
    for(long i=0; i<N; i++) {
        cout << D << " " << N << endl; // Output of this line is shown below till N gets replaced by 0
        cinp >> K[i] >> S[i];
        times[i] = (1.0 * (D - K[i]))/S[i];
        if(max < times[i])
            max = times[i];
    }
    cout << D << " " << N << endl;
    if(t == 3) {
        cout << D << " " << N << endl;
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
            cout << K[i] << " " << S[i] << endl;
    }
    cop << "Case #" << t << ": " << std::setprecision(6) << std::fixed << D/max << endl;
}
```

A glimpse of when it gets replaced

```
912786011 100 <--- Needs to read 100 nos as N is 100
912786011 100
912786011 100
912786011 100
912786011 100
912786011 100
912786011 100
912786011 100
912786011 100
912786011 100
912786011 100
912786011 100
912786011 100
912786011 100
912786011 100
912786011 100
912786011 100
912786011 100
912786011 100
912786011 0 <---------------- Became 0
```

Also, I wanted to know if my conclusion is right then what is a good amount of memory that can be allocated on the stack(without new) ?

Comment: You cannot declare `long K[N]` if `N` is not known at compile time. Worse yet even if you could allocate it at runtime, you don't even read in `N` until after you allocate the array!

Comment: Variable length arrays are illegal in c++ (you are probably using some compiler extension) so you should rather allocate them on the heap.

Comment: Let's assume it's valid C++, it's still undefined behavior because N hasn't been assigned a value prior to use.

Comment: Thank you so much guys. I missed the line totaly.

Comment: @VTT gcc's (and alike) extension called VLA, enabled by default, unless pedantic mode engaged

Comment: On ubuntu 15.10, the default stack size per thread is 8 MBytes.  Remember this limit when setting sizes of K and S.  Also note that a std::vector<Type> is 24 bytes in the automatic storage, regardless of sizeof(Type) and how many Type.  std::vector handles dynamic memory for you. I believe you will find that vectors will feel comfortable, and  meet your expectations and needs.

Comment: This is interesting . So vectors can be on the stack and can be of any size and the compiler handles the memory for me. That's nice. Thanks Douglas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DeiDei said correctly, you've used VLA extension of GCC wrongly.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html

> The length of an array is computed once when the storage is allocated
>   and is remembered for the scope of the array in case you access it
>   with sizeof.

So you had to assign  ( and ensure it by all means) that variable used for size is of proper value BEFORE you declared array. You didn't and you went out of bound of array, reading data in the stack. if this was a function, most likely you'd triggered  run-time error on exit from function.

Variable length is kind of  misnomer for this feature, because resulting array can not change size so its use is quite limited. Best to use std::vector, which you can construct with provided size reserved. VLA were allowed in C99, but are not standard in C++, they aren't portable to other C++ compilers.

Comment: Swift it would be good if you can add vector to be on the stack and not be bound by memory and also the compiler handling the memory for the user.

Comment: vector uses dynamic memory. std::array _may_ use stack memory if small enough